# xcolor: setting/removing the space around the table columns throws an error

Tags: tables, color

The following code works well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \rowcolor{gray!50}
    Table head & Table head\\
    Some values & Some values\\
    Some values & Some values\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

However, when trying to remove the space before/after the first/last column or set it to different length, I get this error:

> Use of @startpbox doesn't match its definition.
>   \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{1mm}}

for

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{1mm}}
    \rowcolor{gray!50}
    Table head & Table head\\
    Some values & Some values\\
    Some values & Some values\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Knowing that I have updated all the packages before running this test.

Comment: Your example compiles without error for me. Show your log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You can find it [here](https://pastebin.com/jGUF7mWY)

Comment: Your colortbl is outdated. Check for updates in user mode.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You got it. However, I wonder why updating in Admin mode doesn't make it right.

Comment: the admin mode can't update your user packages. So always check for updates in both modes.

Comment: Great advice I will keep in mind from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the correct code for the final spacing, it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
\begin{tabular}{c<{\hspace{12pt}}c<{\hspace{1mm}}}
\rowcolor{gray!50} Table head &Table head\\
Some values & Some values\\
Some values & Tome values\\
 \end{tabular}}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. But, may I know why the is the space before the first column still there?

Comment: Oh! I forgot the other side. It's a problem with the overhang. I'll update my answer in a moment.

Comment: @Diaa: I've updated my answer. I had to take  another approach for the colour overhang problem.

Comment: By calculations: the default value of `\tabcolsep` is 6pt, and there are two of them between two columns (with the vertical rule, if any, in the middle).